# MPMoviePlayerController bug or feature: Setting initialPlaybackTime to t seconds hides the time-slider upto t

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Say a movie is 10 min long and I am setting `initialPlaybackTime` to the 1 minute mark, like thus:

```c
NSString *urlStr = @"http://<ip>/vod_movie.m3u8"; // 10 minute long video
MPMoviePlayerController* playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                           initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]] ];
[playerController prepareToPlay];
[playerController setInitialPlaybackTime:60]; // Want to play from the 1 minute mark
```

This results in the video starting to play from the 1 minute mark, but the time-slider hides the part *before* 1 min, so there is no way you can seek backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of `initialPlaybackTime`. I don't know of any recommended solution for what you are trying to do, but you could try setting initialPlaybackTime to -1 and after the video starts playing use `setCurrentPlaybackTime` to scroll to the position in the movie that you want the playback to start at.

Comment: +1, But won't that be sub-optimal because the player would have to buffer twice - once from the beginning initially to be able to start playing, and once more from the new position after `setCurrentPlaybackTime`?

Comment: Yes it would be less than optimal but I don't think there is any built-in or optimized way to give the user the option to scroll through the whole movie when the playback doesn't start at the beginning of the movie.

Comment: Maybe writing a custom UI with its own slider implementation is the way out

Comment: RE a custom slider: you'll still have this problem.  I'm running into that right now.

Comment: thnx @MichaelFrederick